# 429 The custom error module does not recognize this error

Tags: acumatica

Every once in a while, while I'm using Contract-Based Acumatica Web Services API, I receive an error message like so:

```
HTTP 429
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 08 Aug 2019 20:38:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 54

The custom error module does not recognize this error.
```

Comment: The hint is given by the HTTP error code, all other information is rather irrelevant. The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you go over your `Maximum Number of Concurrent Web Services API Requests` or `Maximum Number of Web Services API Requests per Minute` limit.

In the `License Monitoring Console` (`SM604000`) it should show up as a `Declined Number of Web Services Requests`

More information about `License Monitoring Console` (`SM604000`):
https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=06869c57-819d-4626-a5a8-72507e6a79d8